# Scraping with Selenium returns NoSuchElementException error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraping project where I try to extract information from the amazon website. The element I want to scrape in an unordered list in a `bdi tag`. To scrape this information I am using XPath.

This is my code so far

```
self.asin.append(self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//bdi[text()='ASIN']/ancestor::li").text.split(": ")[1])
```

self.asin is a list that holds all the ASIN values extracted from multiple links.

Take a look under product details in this [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071GNLFW2)

I want only the ASIN code itself and nothing else from the list. The above code works well for most links but fails at times. I tried adding `time.sleep(10)` but this still fails. I checked the link where the code fails, but the link does have an ASIN element under product details. Because of the page structure, I feel only XPath works.

I looked online for a solution and found `WebDriverWait` with selenium that will wait until the element is loaded and then scrape the required information. The following code is a sample code I wrote trying out `WebDriverWait`

```
try:
    next_page_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'a-last')))
    next_page_button.click()

except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
```

Is there any way to incorporate `WebDriverWait` with `XPath`

Comment: what about `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//bdi[text()='ASIN']/ancestor::li'))` and then your first line of code

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not know we could do this. I thought we could only pass class_name or ID into that.

Comment: Alternative : `asin = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='averageCustomerReviews']"))).get_attribute("data-asin")`